# TextView doesn't show inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a Fragment class, called from by FragmentTabHost, which does not display nothing.

This is my `ArticulosFragment` class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArticulosFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("App", "asdasdasd");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articulos, container, false);
    }

}
```

I have a simple TextView in the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Articulos"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the app, the log added shows correctly, but the text **Articulos** doesn't.

**Edit:** This is my TabHost class which displays (or should displays) the `ArticulosFragment` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
            android.R.id.tabcontent);

    inicializarTabs();

}

public void inicializarTabs() {

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Articulos");
    spec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
        }
    });
    spec.setIndicator("Articulos");
    tabHost.addTab(spec, ArticulosFragment.class, null);


}
```

Comment: You should post the code of fragment_articulos.xml instead of the screenshot. (There is a little "text" tab a the bottom of the designer)

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Two Things That Might Cause That:

1. Check If The Container coming is null for view
2. Check you Code For Fragment that show Fragment

Try Removing onCreate method from Fragment

Answer (score 0):

**TabContentFactory**

> Makes the content of a tab when it is selected. Use this if your tab
>   content needs to be created on demand, i.e. you are not showing an
>   existing view or starting an activity.

Please notice this line:

**you are not showing an existing view or starting an activity.**

```
public abstract View createTabContent (String tag)

Callback to make the tab contents
Parameters
tag     Which tab was selected.
Returns

    The view to display the contents of the selected tab.
```

So because you have a fragment and it is already have a view you do not need `createTabContent` and the interesting part is:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v13/java/android/support/v13/app/FragmentTabHost.java#L219

as you see fragmentTabHost overwrites your `TabContentFactory`.

anyway your problem is:

```
tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);
```

change it to:

```
tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),R.id.realtabcontent);
```